# How to refactor the controller methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to know if is possible to refactor the same lines of code but in two differnts methods in the controller.

```
class CigsController < ApplicationController
  def home
    Time.zone = 'Amsterdam'
    Groupdate.time_zone = 'Amsterdam'

    @date_now = Time.zone.now
    @day_date_now = @date_now.day

    @cigs = Cig.all
    @a_r_r_today_cigs = Cig.where(date: Time.zone.now.midnight..Time.zone.now)
end
  def index
    Time.zone = 'Amsterdam'
    Groupdate.time_zone = 'Amsterdam'

    @cigs = Cig.all
    @a_r_r_today_cigs = Cig.where(date: Time.zone.now.midnight..Time.zone.now)
  end
```

Comment: You may want to ask this on the [code review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `before_action` (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)

```
class CigsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_variables, only: [:home, :index]

  def home
    @date_now = Time.zone.now
    @day_date_now = @date_now.day
  end

  def index
  end

  private

  def set_variables
    Time.zone = 'Amsterdam'
    Groupdate.time_zone = 'Amsterdam'

    @cigs = Cig.all
    @a_r_r_today_cigs = Cig.where(date: Time.zone.now.midnight..Time.zone.now)
  end
end
```

Or you could just call the method manually:

```
class CigsController < ApplicationController
  def home
    set_variables
    @date_now = Time.zone.now
    @day_date_now = @date_now.day
  end

  def index
    set_variables
  end

  private

  def set_variables
    Time.zone = 'Amsterdam'
    Groupdate.time_zone = 'Amsterdam'

    @cigs = Cig.all
    @a_r_r_today_cigs = Cig.where(date: Time.zone.now.midnight..Time.zone.now)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @luisenrike and Garrett_Motzner. It works fine. Finally I have done it manually.